# How to inherit java.sql.Connection in GWT?

Tags: gwt

> [ERROR] Line 29: No source code is available for type
>   java.sql.Connection; did you forget to inherit a required module?
>         [ERROR] Line 35: No source code is available for type java.sql.Statement; did you forget to inherit a required module?
>         [ERROR] Line 45: No source code is available for type java.sql.ResultSet; did you forget to inherit a required module?
>         [ERROR] Line 52: No source code is available for type java.text.SimpleDateFormat; did you forget to inherit a required
>   module?
>         [ERROR] Line 68: No source code is available for type java.util.GregorianCalendar; did you forget to inherit a required
>   module?
>         [ERROR] Line 90: No source code is available for type java.sql.SQLException; did you forget to inherit a required module?

Answer (score 1):

You can't just put any code in GWT client side. GWT Java code is compiled into Javascript and deployed on your browser, so only a subset [(*)](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsCompatibility.html) of Java is supported, and `java.SQL` is not part of it. Besides SQL connections are something you don't want to put client side. Maybe you can use a native Javascript framework to accomplish this (but likely you still don't want it ;-)